# How To Get Sum of Column Desired Selected Dates

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf

**Here is Database picture**

[Click here to Show Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMv3L.png)

**Back-end Code of my Design**

```
if (startdate.Text == "" || enddate.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Select The Date");
        }
        else
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Here i need query for total bags", con);
            SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            reader.Read();
            string val = reader.GetValue(0).ToString();
            decimal valu = Convert.ToDecimal(val);
            Int32 value = Convert.ToInt32(valu);
            bags.Text = value.ToString();
            con.Close();
        }
```

**Design of my app**

[i need to fetch total bags,sales and profit Click here to Show Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQQ3M.png)

**Here i Need to fill values**

also queries that i need

(1) sum of bags by selected Dates

(1.1) sum of bags by selected Name and Dates

(2) sum of credit by selected Dates

(2.1) sum of credit by selected Name and Dates

(3) sum of profit by selected Dates

(3.1) sum of profit by selected Name and Dates

**Here it is Over all Data Query**

```
select r.id,r.datee,r.time,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.bag,r.price,r.credit,r.debit from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = 'aizaz' and r.datee between '1/1/2016' and '12/12/2017' order by r.datee asc;
```

Comment: Plz mention your problem precisely

Comment: So, whats the problem? you have number 1, keep going adding the criteria you  need (oh and you dont need an orderby when you're just producing 1 number

Comment: see the pictures of database and design

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit your question to include the relevant details in such a way that we can actually help. Sample data should be in the form of DDL + DML statements, and desired results should be clear.

Comment: You should show some effort yourself

Comment: Pictures arent whats needed here - whats needed is why you feel unable to do this.. whats blocking you? lack of knowledge, not understanding the code you have?

Comment: okay... i need only queries where can i get only sum of bags also sum of bags of customer.. see database picture.
select r.id,r.datee,r.time,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.bag,r.price,r.credit,r.debit 
from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id 
and c.name = 'aizaz' and r.datee between '1/1/2016' and '12/12/2017' order by r.datee asc;

Comment: @AizazAhmad Welcome to StackOverflow. This site isn't "please show me how to code this type" but rather "I have worked the problem, but I got stuck at a certain point, and the research I've done was of no help".
Please try writing these queries by yourself, and If you still have a problem - come back to us for help.

Comment: @KamilSolecki Thank you (^_^). can you help me through teamviewer?

Comment: @AizazAhmad Sadly I'm at work now. I might contact you when I have some free time.

Comment: Thankssssss Alooooot @KamilSolecki (^_^)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   select sum(r.bag) as SumOfBags
   from records as r, customer as c
   where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = 'aizaz' and r.datee between '1/1/2016' and '12/12/2017'
```

I'm almost sure that is about to work :)

In case of problems with empty elements you can try

```
   select sum(r.bag) as SumOfBags
   from records as r
   inner join customer as c
   on r.cusid = c.id 
   where r.datee between '1/1/2016' and '12/12/2017' and c.name = 'aizaz'
```

Comment: wow!!!!! Many Many Thanks you such a genius (^_^)

Comment: both queries works great. can you suggest me that which query is more suitable

Comment: Well, sometimes you want to use, lets say id from two tables. Then you can just use "from tab1, tab2". However there is some possibility that you will not find some id's in one of table. What then? That is the moment where joins are comming in. All the details you want to can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1UKp7.png. The second reason to use join instead of just coma is that can be faster (as more complicated query is, as "join" becames better).

Comment: hm.. got it! got it

Comment: Do you have any idea how can i get this value

Comment: SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select sum(r.bag) as Total from records as r inner join customer as c on r.cusid = c.id where r.datee between '" + startdate.Text + "' and '" + enddate.Text + "' and c.name = '" + name + "'", con);
                 SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                 reader.Read();
                 string val = reader[0].ToString();
                 MessageBox.Show(val);

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/182327/SqlDataReader-Simplified

Comment: i have solved now.. now next thing is that both datepickers throws xx/xx/xxx format but i need xx-xx-xxx or xxx/xx/xx format because my database fill with xxx/xx/xx format

Comment: I'll tell you the secret that only developers can handle :) There is no such fing like "date format". TimeDate is just a date and time encrypted somehow, however you can display it in different ways. Like myDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy"). Caution! "m" stands for minute, "M" is month!

Comment: One more thing! "dd" means you count days like 01, 02, 03... To skip 0 you have to use single "d". Then it goes 1,2,3...10,11,12... So in your case myDate.ToString("d/M/yyyy") might be better

Comment: @ Arkadiusz Raszeja really you deserve an award! (y). problem solved All Queries working Perfectly! now last thing is more horrible for me hehehehe that is Total Gross Sale... am so weak in sql, database structure bal bla bla

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
Select Dates, Names, sum(bag) as SumOfBags
from TableName
group by Dates
```

1.1)

```
Select Dates, sum(bag) as SumOfBags
from TableName
group by Dates, Names
```

Of if you want to just select single value 
1)

```
Select sum(bag) as SumOfBags
from TableName
where Date  = WhatEverYouWant
```

1.1)

```
 Select sum(bag) as SumOfBags
from TableName
where Dates = WhatEverYouWant and Names = WhatEverYouWant
```

I belive you are able to create other queries now :)

Comment: i think 2nd one that i need... thankss let me try

Comment: can you edit that query select r.id,r.datee,r.time,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.bag,r.price,r.credit,r.debit 
from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id 
and c.name = 'aizaz' and r.datee between '1/1/2016' and '12/12/2017' order by r.datee asc;

Comment: this query showing all records

Comment: thanks for your effort but u need to under stand am joing the name from other table thats why query looks like this select r.id,r.datee,r.time,c.name,r.description,r.vanda,r.bag,r.pri‌​ce,r.credit,r.debit from records as r, customer as c where r.cusid = c.id and c.name = 'aizaz' and r.datee between '1/1/2016' and '12/12/2017' order by r.datee asc
and you need to edit this. and i need only one cell as result

Answer (score 0):

Super quick guide to SQL :) 
The easiest query goes like this:

```
select <List of columns you want to be shown>
from <table name>
where <conditions you want>
```

If you want to get sum you need to write 
`sum(<column to be sumed>) as <alias for this column>`
 And you need to use this construction AS ONE OF THE COLUMNS YOU WANT TO BE SHOWN (after select). Like in example of 1.1